# Send data from .txt file to JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, file, geolocation

I have following **simple.txt** file:

```
new google.maps.LatLng(37.782551, -122.445368)
new google.maps.LatLng(37.754665, -122.403242)
new google.maps.LatLng(37.753837, -122.403172)
new google.maps.LatLng(37.752986, -122.403112)
new google.maps.LatLng(37.751266, -122.403355)
```

following JavaScript code:

```
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.774546, -122.433523),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

  var pointArray = new google.maps.MVCArray(taxiData);

  heatmap = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({
    data: pointArray
  });

  heatmap.setMap(map);
}
```

and following array:

```
    var taxiData = [ 
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.782551, -122.445368)
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.754665, -122.403242)
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.753837, -122.403172)
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.752986, -122.403112)
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.751266, -122.403355)
];
```

I would like to send my data from **simple.txt** to **taxiData** array in JavaScript. 
I have tried something like this (without success):

```
var taxiData = [
    <?php
    echo file_get_contents("simple.txt");
    ?>
];
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to separate the array elements with commas. You can do that easily enough in PHP:

```
<?php echo implode(',', explode('\n', file_get_contents("simple.txt"))); ?>
```

That simply breaks the file into an array of newline-delimited elements, then joins them back together using commas, creating a valid format that can be passed into the JavaScript code without issue.